# CPU overheating on Linux, but not on Windows, while doing the same things

Tags: linux, cpu, intel, temperature

I can clearly hear the fans (there are 2 of them) inside my laptop spin more on Linux Mint 18.2 Cinnamon 64-bit with kernel 4.10.0-37-generic, but any kernel I've tried for that matter, than on Windows 10 Pro. What is more important, my laptop's cooling does not keep up for the temperatures, as shows this `dmesg` snippet:

```
[10498.701800] CPU1: Package temperature above threshold, cpu clock throttled (total events = 2582)
[10498.701802] CPU4: Package temperature above threshold, cpu clock throttled (total events = 2582)
[10498.701804] CPU7: Package temperature above threshold, cpu clock throttled (total events = 2582)
[10498.701805] CPU0: Package temperature above threshold, cpu clock throttled (total events = 2582)
[10498.701806] CPU3: Package temperature above threshold, cpu clock throttled (total events = 2582)
[10498.701807] CPU5: Package temperature above threshold, cpu clock throttled (total events = 2582)
[10498.701809] CPU2: Package temperature above threshold, cpu clock throttled (total events = 2582)
[10498.701816] CPU6: Package temperature above threshold, cpu clock throttled (total events = 2582)
```

with 2582 of these events in `uptime -p` of 3 hours, I don't know what does this Linux otherwise than the Windows.

I must stress that I am using this Linux for a long time, and it always had this issue. And I start worrying about my CPU in the long-run.

I tried installing `intel-microcode` in Driver Manager. Did not change a thing.

For example, I am playing a browser game based on Flash Player in Chrome.

The CPU in question is Intel Core i7 4700HQ.

---

EDIT1:

```
ps -aux
```

output (expired on pastebin).

Comment: First of you might want to check what process is using up all your resources. I think it won't be the flash game. You can try opening a terminal and type `sudo su` and then `top` and see what is using your CPU. You can also use `htop` which is more advanced, but might not be preinstalled.

Comment: Actually, `ps -aux` might be better suited, especially if you post it (because it outputs everything in text instead of being interactive). Keep in mind that it may contain personal data; review before posting. Also you should, of course, execute it at a time when the fan is speeding up.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I may have found a solution:

```
sudo apt-get install thermald
```

This package should do the following:

> Thermal daemon looks for thermal sensors and thermal cooling drivers in the Linux thermal sysfs (/sys/class/thermal) and builds a list of sensors and cooling drivers. Each of the thermal sensors can optionally be binded to a cooling drivers by the in kernel drivers. In this case the Linux kernel thermal core can directly take actions based on the temperature trip points, for each sensor and associated cooling device. For example a trip temperature X in a sensor can be associates a cooling driver Y. So when the sensor temperature = X, the cooling driver "Y" is activated.

Since I installed it and rebooted, I have only 4 occurrences of overheating with uptime of 2 hours.

I wonder, why this useful package was not pre-installed, but never mind.

After I have run 8 simultaneous `sha256sum` of a 100GiB file, CPU was used at 100% for several minutes:

[image: 100% CPU usage]

**Without the `thermald` package, the chassis of the laptop above the CPU would literally burn my fingers when touching it, but now it's only moderately warm!**

Not to mention there is nothing in `dmesg` about CPU throttling.

Comment: Thanks for this! Even Manjaro didn't ship this package for me, not sure why. It successfully brought down my CPU temperature from 95°C to 65°C easily with the same work going on (writing 65GB of data to disk in BTRFS). Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

In my case, **Caribou** was my overheating problem: Running Linux Mint Cinnamon 19 on an Asus i7 (Intel© Core™ i7-2670QM CPU @ 2.20GHz × 4). Badly overheating, up to 97C and causing crashes & slowdowns.  In terminal I typed command **top**, and found that two programs were using ~100% or more CPU time: Thunderbird 52.9.1 and CARIBOU (a virtual keyboard program that I enabled weeks ago but was not using). T-bird did this after I would click, say, on an email. So I went to SOFTWARE MANAGER, typed CARIBOU in the search box, and REMOVED it. Then rebooted. Amazing! Problem solved: CPU cooled off, and T-bird returned to minimal CPU usage. All I can guess is Caribou and T-bird were "fighting" each other. (BTW, one clue was in Win7 the same laptop ran cool, even when I stressed it simultaneously with video and chess.)

Notes: I first got clued in to the overheating problem by checking the file **var/log/syslog** and because of that installed the applet **CPU Temperature Indicator**, while ignoring the function call warning (no problems yet). Using **system monitor** helped me check the terminal top process to ID the big CPU users.

Comment: Have you taking the time to report the issue to Caribou team (they need to have some GitHub but did not manage to find it now). Anyway, thanks for reporting it to us at least...

Answer (score 0):

I have searched the problem over a week and found out that the best solution for me and other friends. Just install `TLP linux advance power management tool` and you are all set.

Trust me, it works and I am wondering why this wonderful tool doesn't came pre installed in most of the linux distros. The link is :

https://linrunner.de/en/tlp/docs/tlp-linux-advanced-power-management.html

Answer (score 0):

UBUNTU 18.04.5 (32 BITS)
kernel LINUX 4.15.0-143 generic i686
MATE 1.20.1

Running TLP and Cpufreq programs.
The first don't stop the overheating, nor the fan overdrive and noise.
Second one keeps crashing, stop working and shooting down.

Did TOP in terminal and the consuming comes from FIREFOX Browser.
Did to stop it via SYSTEM MONITOR and nothing stops the CPU Fan heavy work...
... you close the browser, it stays.
... you restart, it comes again.
... you shut down and wait a day… maybe the overdrive fan starts, maybe not.

LINU-XXX

Comment: Are you answering the original question, or seeking help with your own issue? If you have an issue of your own, please delete this answer and post your own question (and... read the community guidelines on how to ask a good question and what information to include to help us help you resolve it quickly.)